# How do I properly export my model, materials and textures for use in a Fallout 4 mod?

Tags: texturing, materials, export, obj

So I'm brand new to blender, only started learning it last week so sorry in advance if I use the wrong terms, don't provide the right details or am asking something that is impossible to do.

Basically I'm trying to make an armor mod for Fallout 4 and I'm trying to export the meshes so they'll appear in a program called "Outfit Studio". I've managed to get the mesh into the program by importing the .obj and that worked fine, but the textures didn't carry over. Outfit Studio can't import .mtl files and even when I try to import my mesh back into Blender, the textures are completely gone.

I have some procedural textures in the form of rust, and some image textures I made in Photoshop or found online. Fallout requires .dds files for textures, but even getting them out as .png's or something would be good because I'm sure Outfit Studio will read those and convert them in the final export.

I'm not sure what information is required to fix this problem so I'll just attach a photo of the main Blender screen in case it's relevant and of course, let me know what other info or screenshots you may need and I'll make an edit to this post.

[image]

EDIT: Also, as a quick side note, if anyone knows of any good, in-depth, step by step tutorials on how to model, texture, export and convert armor/weapon mods for Fallout 4, Skyrim, or any game with a similar process to those, that would be greatly appreciated because, as I said, I'm very knew to this and I can't find many tutorials for Fallout/Skyrim specific Blender usage and a lot of tutorials for Blender are made with the expectation of using the meshes for animation or renders and so there are parts of the process that deviate and I'm struggling to figure certain things out on my own. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is a link to my .blend file. I have actually included two versions, one that's been decimated and one that hasn't, just in case decimating it has caused issues with the UV maps or something like that. It's also very possible that my topography, UV unwraps or texture/material node graphs are awful because, like I said, I'm very new to Blender so it's also possible I've made a bunch of mistakes and the whole project is a write off, so let me know if that's the case.
Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lJp7Q-mkAsGS8jgc3275Bb4qrNzEgJMF?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Upload your blend file here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok, just did that. I uploaded the version I had from before I decimated everything, just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Export as `FBX`

Select `Path Mode` to `Copy`

Select `Embed Textures` beside `Path Mode`

[image]

Comment: Ok, I tried this and I ran into a fair few issues. The folder the textures were exported to only contained two images, both just .png's I had downloaded and used to texture certain parts, they weren't altered in any way either, just full, plain, square images just like how they were when I downloaded them. The textures I created in Photoshop as well as all the rust textures are misssing. Also, when I port it back into Blender the all the textures are gone from the mesh and I get some weird transparency on certain parts of it too. And for some reason the meshes were tiny in Outfit Studio.

Comment: Try other `Path Mode`, Scale the mesh at the time of export

Comment: Gone through all the path mode options now, no luck with any of them. I think the copy setting did what it's supposed to, the files were placed in a new folder so it clearly tried to export the textures but it didn't get most of them for some reason. I'm really not sure what I've done wrong here.

Comment: Can you share the blend file?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Added a link to my original post for you.

Comment: Didn't get the textures inside the blend file.

Comment: Oh ok, how would I get them in there, would I just link them in the google drive folder, or is there some way I'm supposed to add them to the .blend file itself?

Comment: upload to google drive

Comment: Ok, uploaded them all now. Think that's all of them but let me know if anything's still missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127792/discussion-between-karan-and-mvp-teku).